# Codeigniter - How to pass JSON to JS file in assets folder?

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I am trying to pass json from my cotroller to my JS in assets folder

Here is my `container.js` :

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Umur',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: <?php echo json_encode($based_on_age); ?>
    }],
  });
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function index(){
    $sbow=array();

    foreach ($this->m_data->based_on_weeks()->result_array() as $row) {
        $sbow[]=array($row['range'],(float)$row['total']);
    }
    $data['based_on_weeks'] = $sbow;

    $this->load->assets?(container.js,$data); //is there a way to pass data to assets?
    $this->load->view('state.html');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe, you can simply pass your data to your view file. & you will have that data in your JS file as well. Just create a variable in your view file in script tag & it will be accessible in your `container.js' file

You can use like

```
var highChartData = <?php echo json_encode($data["based_on_weeks"])?>;
```

and in container.js, you can do

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Umur',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: highChartData
    }],
  });
```

Comment: You would probably want to change `'<?php echo $data['based_on_weeks']?>';` to `<?php echo json_encode($data['based_on_weeks'])?>;` (json_encodeand without the wrapping quotes) since it seems like the OP wants json.

Comment: Use `window.highChartData` if you wish to avoid warnings from JSHint.

Comment: when I tried this, I couldn't pass my variabel from my view to my js. It's always show undefined value in `highChartData`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are looking to do this won't work, as CodeIgniter is a PHP framework, and therefore runs on the server side, and the container.js file, being JavaScript is client side.  Putting data/content into client side items isn't something which is done, unless you build those files and server them dynamically each time.

Along with the answer from @AgamBanga, you could also do the following directly in your view file (though you either need to include that view each time, or have it in every view you want the chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Umur',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: <?php echo json_encode($data['based_on_weeks'])?>
    }],
  });
```